# Java homework help, using constructors and methods

Tags: java, methods, constructor

Can someone please explain the following problem to me? I'm not looking for you to answer it for me but rather for you to explain it to me so I can get going in the correct direction.  I've been struggling in this class... I taught myself html and css and can write it fluently like the back of my hand.  So when I signed up for this class I thought I would pick up on java easily too... man was I wrong :)

```
public class TestGlass 
{ 
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        Glass milk = new Glass(15); // 15 ounces of milk 
        Glass juice = new Glass(3); // 3 ources of juice 

        milk.drink(2); 
        milk.drink(1); 

        milk.report(); 

        juice.fill(6);  // went from 3 to 9 ounces 
        juice.drink(1); // now down to 8 ounces 

        juice.report();  

        juice.spill(); 

        juice.report(); 
   } 
} 

class Glass 
{ 
   // Declare a variable to keep track of the number of ounces in a glass here 


   // Write the methods here.  You will need a constructor, plus the drink, report, fill, 
   // and spill methods.  These methods are for any generic glass -- they are not specific  
   // to the milk or juice instances of a glass (i.e., you should not mention "juice" or  
   // "milk" inside the Glass class). 

}
```

And this is what the output is supposed to look like...

Glass has 12 ounces.
Glass has 8 ounces.
Glass has 0 ounces.

Comment: What exactly do you need clarification on?

Comment: Virtually any basic java tutorial will show you an example of constructors and methods. I suggest you use google.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the comment block that the professor helpfully inserted for you:

```
// Declare a variable to keep track of the number of ounces in a glass here 


// Write the methods here.  You will need a constructor, plus the drink, report, fill, 
// and spill methods.  These methods are for any generic glass -- they are not specific  
// to the milk or juice instances of a glass (i.e., you should not mention "juice" or  
// "milk" inside the Glass class).
```

It looks like you should:

- Declare a variable to keep track of the number of ounces in a glass at the beginning of the class.
- Write a:

  - Constructor taking one parameter for the number of ounces.
  - `drink` method subtracting the number of ounces passed to the method from the number of ounces.
  - `fill` method to add the number of ounces passed to the number of ounces.
  - `spill` method to set the number of ounces to 0, because it all spilled out.
  - `report` method that prints:

    ```
    Glass has <number of ounces> ounces.
    ```

    where `<number of ounces>` is the number of ounces from the variable.

After that, you are done.

Comment: here's a fun bonus he could add: throw an exception if you try to drink more than what the glass contains!

Comment: @Sam_D If the OP is just catching up on java, maybe he shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to write the constructor and methods of class Glass so that the test compiles, runs and produces the expected output. This is an example of Test Driven Development - the test is written first, then the implementation of the tested object.